# Error Xcode: Status bar could not find cached time string image

Tags: swift, xcode

Desde que actualice a Xcode 9.3 me sale este error:

> Status bar could not find cached time string image. Rendering
>   in-process.

¿Sabeís que es o porque puede suceder?

Inicialmente todo va bien y no me da error la aplicación en ningún punto.

Gracias por vuestra ayuda, saludos.

Comment: Has visto esto? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49586341/status-bar-could-not-find-cached-time-string-image-rendering-in-process

Comment: @Spidvmp Si, lo he estado revisando pero nada, sigue el mensaje saliendo. Tal vez sea algún fallo de XCode. A ver si la siguiente actualización desaparece.

Comment: Prueba con hacer un clean del proyecto y después borrar la carpeta llamada "derived data", hecho esto cierra, vuelve a abrir y haz un build.

Comment: @Denis No encuentro la carpeta 'derivered data'. ¿Donde está ubicada?